# Divide a Python dataframe into groups, do operations, and reconnect the groups into the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to get the difference of commute time between multiple stops on subway trips. So my dataframe currently looks like:

```
route  date              trip_id                                    
1   2015-07-10 23:35:45 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-10 23:40:50 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-10 23:45:54 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-10 23:50:57 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-10 23:56:00 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:01:07 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:06:10 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:11:13 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:16:15 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:21:17 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:26:19 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:31:24 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:36:27 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:41:29 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:46:32 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-11 00:51:34 000550_1..S02X020
1   2015-07-07 00:05:51 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:06:02 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:11:03 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:16:05 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:21:08 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:26:14 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:31:18 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:36:20 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:41:26 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:46:28 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:51:31 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 00:56:36 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 01:01:39 000650_1..S02X016
1   2015-07-07 01:06:41 000650_1..S02X016
... ... ... 
1   2015-07-09 01:21:53 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-09 01:26:55 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-09 01:32:00 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-09 01:37:03 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-09 01:42:05 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-09 01:47:10 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-09 01:52:12 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-09 01:57:14 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-09 02:02:17 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-09 02:07:20 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 00:29:12 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 00:34:14 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 00:39:19 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 00:44:21 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 00:49:25 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 00:54:30 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 00:59:32 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 01:04:35 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 01:09:38 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 01:14:40 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 01:24:46 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 01:29:48 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 01:34:50 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 01:39:57 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 01:45:00 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 01:50:03 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 01:55:06 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 02:00:12 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 02:05:14 149900_1..N02X020
1   2015-07-10 02:10:17 149900_1..N02X020
```

There are 800+ different trip ids and for each trip id I want to take the difference of the time between any given stop within the trip and the original station. I figured the easiest way to do this would be to split the dataframe into each individual trip id a set up a function that will take the difference of the date value of each row and the date value of the first row within the group.

If there is a more optimized way of doing this please let me know as well!

Edit -

Just to add on an example, I'm hoping for something like the following -

```
1   2015-07-11 00:11:13 000550_1..S02X020   NaN
1   2015-07-11 00:16:15 000550_1..S02X020   05:02
1   2015-07-11 00:21:17 000550_1..S02X020   10:14
1   2015-07-11 00:26:19 000550_1..S02X020   15:06
1   2015-07-11 00:31:24 000550_1..S02X020   20:11
1   2015-07-11 00:36:27 000550_1..S02X020   25:14
1   2015-07-11 00:41:29 000550_1..S02X020   30:16
```

If you look at the last column, each value is equal to the corresponding row's date value minus the "originating station" which is the first row's date value

Comment: Could you show us your expected output? Anyways, splitting is almost always one of the most inefficient ways to do that. A `groupby` and maybe a `apply(lambda x:)` are the ways to go.

Comment: @JuanC Yup, I've added an example to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Also if you could remove columns that are irrelevant to this question, might also help. Right now it's a bit hard to navigate your question

Comment: @JuanC got it, hope that helps

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand your problem. Give me a few minutes and I'll help you !

Comment: Do you need the difference to be in that format? Could it be a float of number of minutes. Say, the first row would be  `5.03333` instead of `5:02`

Comment: @JuanC That should be fine, I can format it back later down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby.apply` is slow here ideally use `groupby.transform` to create a series with the first value of date for each ID and then subtract from the date column this new series.
Assuming the times are ordered we would do:

```
#df['date']=pd.to_datetime(d['date']) #if date is string -> convert to datetime
df['difference']=df['date'].sub(df.groupby('trip_id').date.transform('first'))
```

---

if they are messy, use `DataFrame.sort_values` ​​first:

```
df['difference']=df['date'].sub(df.sort_values('date').groupby('trip_id').date.transform('first'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df2 = df.groupby('trip_id').apply(lambda x: x-x.iloc[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had a couple of errors when implementing it but I think I've got it now :)

Comment: Nice, I'm glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

[diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) is the pandas function you are looking for:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date])
df.diffs = df.groupby('trip_id').diff()
```

or if your dates are not sorted, sort them first:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date])
df.sort_values(by=['date']).groupby('trip_id').diff()
```